# Amazon: How do I clear text search and see just the category

Tags: amazon

Here's something that I've been trying to do for a long time without success.

Let's say I'm searching for something on Amazon, and this is the search page I'm on:

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=e27+led+bulb&i=tools&rh=n%3A228013%2Cn%3A322525011%2Cn%3A2314207011&dc&crid=IP2VNPZRSOWZ&qid=1569659967&rnid=2941120011&sprefix=e27+%2Caps%2C275&ref=sr_hi_3

You can see the breadcrumbs for this page:

[image]

I'm inside a category, and in that category, I've filtered for a certain search text. Since the search text is redundant at this point, I'd like to remove it completely, and just visit the "LED Bulbs" category without any text search.

The only way I know how to do it is to try to reach that category independently of that page, by searching on Google or browsing on Amazon.

Is there a more direct way to get to the category from the page I'm on?

Comment: A few years ago there was an "x" that could do just that. They got rid of the "x", and it seems there's no longer any way to have no search text. The name of the category as the search text appears to be their preferred replacement.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work when simply delete the keyword search from the URL, in this case the `k=e27+led+bulb&`.